# Self-hosted fonts not loading in app. I am using @font-face and self hosted fonts in app server

Tags: css, font-face, self-hosting

I am hosting fonts in my server and it can be accessed like - `https://cdn.mywebsite/fonts/font-name`
Now I have a css file (in the same folder as index.html) where I am importing these using `@font-face` like this:

```
        font-family: 'fontname';
        src:url('https://cdn.mywebsite.com/fonts/font-name.woff2') format('woff2'),
          url('https://cdn.mywebsite.com/fonts/font-name.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
      }

      @font-face {
        font-family: 'fontname';
        src:url('https://cdn.mywebsite.com/fonts/font-name-light.woff2') format('woff2'),
          url('https://cdn.mywebsite.com/fonts/font-name-light.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: italic;
      }
...... and a few more
```

I tried importing this file in my index.html using 2 methods, both returning 404 error in network tab.

1.

```
<style type='text/css'>
  @import url('fonts.css');
</style>
```

2. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts.css"/>`
   In #2, I've tried to use `src/..../fonts.css` and `./fonts.css` and `/fonts.css` (similar tries for #1 too)

I am not sure what's happening and why its not working.

NOW what IS working is adding the css directly within  component like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
        font-family: 'fontname';
        src:url('https://cdn.mywebsite.com/fonts/font-name.woff2') format('woff2'),
          url('https://cdn.mywebsite.com/fonts/font-name.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
      }

      @font-face {
        font-family: 'fontname';
        src:url('https://cdn.mywebsite.com/fonts/font-name-light.woff2') format('woff2'),
          url('https://cdn.mywebsite.com/fonts/font-name-light.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: italic;
      }
</style>
```

I'm using node express and react (but that shouldn't matter, I think).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do the fonts live in your server directory structure?  `https://cdn/mywebsite/fonts` is not a valid URL.  `cdn` is the hostname in that URL.  You are going to need something like `http://mysitedomain.com/fonts` where `fonts` is the directory under your public directory for serving static files.

Comment: apologies, i'll correct my link it is `https://cdn/mywebsite.com/fonts` fonts is in `src/main/fonts` same as `src/main/index.html`

Comment: https://cdn.mywebsite.com/fonts

Answer (score 0):

A few things to look at.

1. `https://cdn/mywebsite.com/fonts/font-name.woff2` is not a valid URL, because `cdn` is not a valid hostname. You need `https://cdn.mywebsite.com/fonts/font-name.woff2` or maybe something like `https://cdn.example.com/mywebsite.com/fonts/font-name.woff2` for the woff2 font file object.
2. Your css needs to mention more than just the woff2 font file to work cross-browser. You need other formats too. Here's an example of part of a workable css file for FontAwesome. (See this. https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'),
       url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'), 
       url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Your favorite search engine will find several online tools for creating web font assets, including the CSS files and the various font file formats.

Comment: typo, sorry. I fixed it to cdn.mywebsite

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.mywebsite.com/fonts/myfont.woff">`
When i do this, its accessing the font, but font isn't loading. I added the font to css file too.

Comment: Shouldn't this work too? <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css" type="text/css"> There are no errors in the console but network tag shows 404 error on the call.